# ClickOnce application suddenly fails on download dll (Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll)

Tags: .net, iis, office-interop, clickonce

I have a clickonce application that suddenly started to get an error while downloading a specific dll (Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll). No changes have been made to the application, nor to the public server from which it is downloaded.

The same application also uses the Excel dll, and that is downloaded without problems.

If during the download I stop downloading the dll with Fiddler (aborting the HTTP session), ClickOnce automatically retries to download it and this time the download completes successfully.

If I try to download the dll from any browser, using the URL that I find in the error log, the download is completed without problems.

On PC with Windows Server the installation is successful, but not on Windows 7 and Windows 10.

What could be the cause?

EDIT: Here the verbose log --> https://pastebin.com/qunawf8V

```
INFORMAZIONI VERSIONE PIATTAFORMA
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    clr.dll             : 4.8.4069.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    dfdll.dll           : 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

ORIGINI
    URL distribuzione           : file:///C:/Users/admin/Downloads/CreditoLab.application
    URL provider distribuzione      : http://dynamica-creditolab.dynamicaretail.it/Dynamica/http/CreditoLab.application
                        Server      : Microsoft-IIS/8.0
                        X-Tecnologia    : ASP.NET
    URL applicazione            : http://dynamica-creditolab.dynamicaretail.it/Dynamica/http/deploy_2_1_0_0/CreditoLab.exe.manifest
                        Server      : Microsoft-IIS/8.0
                        X-Tecnologia    : ASP.NET

IDENTITÀ
    Identità distribuzione      : CreditoLab - Dynamica.app, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9e0747e92f116fb2, processorArchitecture=msil
    Identità applicazione       : CreditoLab - Dynamica.exe, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9e0747e92f116fb2, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

RIEPILOGO APPLICAZIONE
    * Applicazione installabile.

RIEPILOGO ERRORI
    Quello che segue è un riepilogo degli errori. Informazioni dettagliate su tali errori sono disponibili più avanti nel registro.
    * L'attivazione di C:\Users\admin\Downloads\CreditoLab.application ha causato un'eccezione. Sono stati rilevati i messaggi di errore seguenti:
        + Impossibile scaricare http://dynamica-creditolab.dynamicaretail.it/Dynamica/http/deploy_2_1_0_0/Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll.
        + Timeout dell'operazione.

RIEPILOGO ERRORI TRANSAZIONE ARCHIVIO COMPONENTI
    Nessun errore di transazione rilevato.

AVVISI
    Nessun avviso durante l'operazione.

STATO OPERAZIONE
    * [21/06/2021 11:14:26] : Attivazione di C:\Users\admin\Downloads\CreditoLab.application avviata.
    * [21/06/2021 11:14:26] : Elaborazione del manifesto di distribuzione completata.
    * [21/06/2021 11:14:26] : Installazione dell'applicazione avviata.
    * [21/06/2021 11:14:26] : Elaborazione del manifesto dell'applicazione completata.
    * [21/06/2021 11:14:28] : Trovata una versione Runtime compatibile 2.0.50727.
    * [21/06/2021 11:14:28] : Rilevamento dell'assembly dipendente Sentinel.v3.5Client, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=msil utilizzando Sentinel.v3.5Client, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [21/06/2021 11:14:28] : Rilevamento dell'assembly dipendente System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil utilizzando System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [21/06/2021 11:14:28] : Richiesta del trust e rilevamento della piattaforma completati.

DETTAGLI ERRORI
    Durante l'operazione sono stati rilevati gli errori seguenti.
    * [21/06/2021 11:19:37] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Sottotipo sconosciuto)
        - Impossibile scaricare http://dynamica-creditolab.dynamicaretail.it/Dynamica/http/deploy_2_1_0_0/Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll.
        - Origine: System.Deployment
        - Analisi dello stack:
            in System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            in System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            in System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
            in System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- Fine traccia dello stack da posizione precedente dove è stata generata l'eccezione ---
            in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Eccezione interna ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Timeout dell'operazione.
        - Origine: System
        - Analisi dello stack:
            in System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
            in System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

DETTAGLI TRANSAZIONE ARCHIVIO COMPONENTI
    Nessuna informazione disponibile sulla transazione.
```

Comment: Is the add-in running when you try to uninstall it? It seems the add-in was installed previously and you re-deploy it, right?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to embedding interop types into the add-in assembly, so after that you don't need to deploy this assembly any longer.

Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the common language runtime supports embedding type information for COM types directly into managed assemblies, instead of requiring the managed assemblies to obtain type information for COM types from interop assemblies. Because the embedded type information includes only the types and members that are actually used by a managed assembly, two managed assemblies might have very different views of the same COM type. Each managed assembly has a different Type object to represent its view of the COM type. The common language runtime supports type equivalence between these different views for interfaces, structures, enumerations, and delegates. Read more about that in the [Type equivalence and embedded interop types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/type-equivalence-and-embedded-interop-types) article.

Comment: The strange thing is that no changes and no releases have been made. From one day to the next that dll is no longer downloaded, while that of Excel does. I don't want to do a new deployment, but understand what caused the problem. Some idea? Thanks

P.S.: My application is based on .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: Did you re-install the application? It seems you need to clean up the problematic machine and install the add-in anew.